# Java- how to parse for words in a string for a specific word

Tags: java, string, parsing, words

How would I parse for the word "hi" in the sentence "hi, how are you?"
 or in parse for the word "how" in "how are you?"?

example of what I want in code:

```
String word = "hi";
String word2 = "how";
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\n");
String s = scan.nextLine();
if(s.equals(word)) {
System.out.println("Hey");
}
if(s.equals(word2)) {
System.out.println("Hey");
}
```

Comment: What problem have you noticed with your current version?

Comment: Two problems: you test for equality of strings without considering that a line could include spaces, commas, exclamation points etc. and  without caring for upper/lowercase. See my answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To just find the substring, you can use `contains` or `indexOf` or any other variant:

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

```
if( s.contains( word ) ) {
   // ...
}

if( s.indexOf( word2 ) >=0 ) {
   // ...
}
```

If you care about word boundaries, then `StringTokenizer` is probably a good approach.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

You can then perform a case-insensitive check (equalsIgnoreCase) on each word.

Comment: Wow! Thats exactly what I was looking for! btw: in my actual version i had converted it to lowercase already, I just simplified it for the question! Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a job for [Regular Expressions](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). `Contains` would give a false positive on, say, `"hire-purchase"`.

```
if (Pattern.match("\\bhi\\b", stringToMatch)) { //...
```

Comment: A hit-and-run downvote with no explanation? Are you really trying to improve SO, or just throwing away your own rep to try and hurt others'?

Comment: Hey sorry, didnt see that there were other answers down here :p

I tried it, but it doesnt seem to work at all... any thing that I might have done possibly wrong? btw: it gives me an error when i use "match" so i use "matches"

Comment: +1 Except you need to double escape `\\b` for it work correctly. Updating answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go for the `java.util.StringTokenizer`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(
    "Hi, how are you?", 
    ",.:?! \t\n\r"       //whitespace and puntuation as delimiters
);
 while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     if(st.nextToken().equals("Hi")){
         //matches "Hi"
     }
 }
```

Alternatively, take a look at `java.util.regex` and use regular expressions.

Comment: The javadoc for `StringTokenizer` contains the sentence: "`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead."

Comment: Simon Nickerson: thanks for pointing that out, I didn't realize. Pity they favour `split` since that seems to do all the work up front

Comment: what would happen if the user just typed in "hi"? there is no " " anymore after it.

Comment: @Custard: have you tried? For me, the string tokenizer correctly passes "hi" on `nextToken()`

Comment: I havent, (sorry), but I am interested!  Ill get to it tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a [tokenizer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), instead.
Set space and other elements like commas, full stops etc. as delimiters. And rememeber to compare in case-insensitive mode.

This way you can find "hi" in "Hi, how is his test going" without getting a false positive on "his" and a false negative on "Hi" (starts with a uppercase H).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a regular expression to the `next()` method of [`Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).  So you can iterate through each word in the input (Scanner delimits on whitespace by default) and perform the appropriate processing if you get a match.